# How can I convert this data to .CSV from this deeply nested XML file?

Tags: xml, csv, t-sql

I have a large dictionary XML file that is 105MB big. Below is a sample of how it's nested:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE lexdataset
  SYSTEM "CollexML.dtd">
 <superentry id="u583c10bfdbd326ba.31865a51.12110e76de1.-326"><entry publevel="2" id="u583c10bfdbd326ba.31865a51.12110e76de1.-325"><hwblk><hwgrp><hwunit><hw>aah</hw></hwunit></hwgrp></hwblk><datablk><gramcat publevel="2"><pospgrp><pospunit><posp value="verb"/></pospunit></pospgrp><sensecat publevel="2"><defgrp><defunit><def>exclaim in pleasure</def></defunit></defgrp></sensecat></gramcat></datablk></entry></superentry>
<superentry><entry publevel="2"><hwblk><hwgrp><hwunit form="inflected"><hw>aahed</hw></hwunit></hwgrp></hwblk><datablk><xrefgrp><xrefunit publevel="2"><xref superentryid="u583c10bfdbd326ba.31865a51.12110e76de1.-326" xrefid="u583c10bfdbd326ba.31865a51.12110e76de1.-325"><xrhw publevel="2">aah</xrhw></xref></xrefunit></xrefgrp></datablk></entry></superentry>
<superentry><entry publevel="2"><hwblk><hwgrp><hwunit form="inflected"><hw>aahing</hw></hwunit></hwgrp></hwblk><datablk><xrefgrp><xrefunit publevel="2"><xref superentryid="u583c10bfdbd326ba.31865a51.12110e76de1.-326" xrefid="u583c10bfdbd326ba.31865a51.12110e76de1.-325"><xrhw publevel="2">aah</xrhw></xref></xrefunit></xrefgrp></datablk></entry></superentry>
<superentry><entry publevel="2"><hwblk><hwgrp><hwunit form="inflected"><hw>aahs</hw></hwunit></hwgrp></hwblk><datablk><xrefgrp><xrefunit publevel="2"><xref superentryid="u583c10bfdbd326ba.31865a51.12110e76de1.-326" xrefid="u583c10bfdbd326ba.31865a51.12110e76de1.-325"><xrhw publevel="2">aah</xrhw></xref></xrefunit></xrefgrp></datablk></entry></superentry>
</lexdataset>
```

To me, it's very difficult to read and I'm unsure how to go about outputting it. Anyone have any ideas?

All I'd like to do is extract these things:
The word itself
The definition, 
Whether or not a word is inflected or a derivation

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: I've tried using XQuery but can't really make sense of it at the minute. Otherwise I'm open to any languages that are suitable for a file like this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this question through search, I ended up just inserting the rows into a new table in MS SQL Server with the following syntax:

```
select
 WordID         = IDENTITY(INT,1,1),
 a.b.value('(hwblk/hwgrp/hwunit/hw/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(250)') as [Word],
 a.b.value('(datablk/xrefgrp/xrefunit/xref/xrhw/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(250)') as [Derivation],
 a.b.value('(datablk/gramcat/sensecat/defgrp/defunit/def/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(250)') as [Definition],
 a.b.value('(datablk/gramcat/pospgrp/pospunit/posp/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(30)') as [POSP],
 a.b.value('(hwblk/hwgrp/hwunit/@form)[1]', 'nvarchar(30)') as [Form],
 a.b.value('(@publevel)', 'int') as [Ambiguity]
 into Dictionary

from [dbo].[DictionaryXML] c 
cross apply c.xmldata.nodes('lexdataset/superentry/entry') a(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to try the CSV module of BaseX. For more details: http://docs.basex.org/wiki/CSV_Module